# Triggering event when ListBox.Item's size changes

Tags: c#, winforms, listboxitem

I want to update/call some function, when my `ListBox.Items.Count` changes. On addition to `ListBox` or on removal of the items, how to trigger a function?

Comment: How you add/remove the items? You should hook up the logic there.

Comment: I have linked the listbox with AsyncBindingList. Which updates items on listbox. But Don't know how to capture when items count changes. Thank you.

Comment: It should have events AddingNew/ListChanged, what about handling those?

Comment: Do you use WPF, WinForms, Asp.Net ??

Comment: Application is developing in WinForms C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I am using  AsyncBindingList and which is running on Background Worker thread. And  AsyncBindingList is connected to my ListBox. So when my Worker thread finishes its work, it will update  AsyncBindingList in return it will update my listBox on the form.

But On addition of items on list box, I was looking for calling a method which updates other controls. so, Finally I got the solution.

Solution is when work thread finishes it's work, it will call RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler. When It calls a Method through RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler, I triggered Forms.Invoke method, which triggered a method on in the form class, which inturn updated all the controls.

But I really don't know is this is the best way to do it. If you have any suggestion. Please post as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

There are no events for this action. You will either need to do one of the following:

1. make a thread that pulls this information and alerts you (sucks)
2. override a listbox and expose these make the events (ok but why?)
3. simply add the code you need at the places where you add and remove to the listbox (what most people do)

really i think 3 is the way to go.

Comment: I found the solution, check my answer

Answer (score 1):

You could use an [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) as the datasource for the listbox. Then you can create handlers for the [CollectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653375.aspx) event.

Comment: I found the solution, check my answer